# Jest test suite failing for one component

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I have no clue why one of my test suites is failing. I don't think there is any issue with configuration as every single test suite except this is passed. I just took a reference from another component and written this but it never passed. Below is the component, spec file and error that I am facing.

**Component:**

```
 import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { InvestmentSharedService, InvestmentStrategyDigitalDataService } from '@fmr-pl000139/investment/shared/services';
    import { SummaryContent } from './model/summary-content';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'investment-summary-content',
      templateUrl: './summary-content.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./summary-content.component.scss']
    })
    export class SummaryContentComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() tridionContent: { [key: string]: string };
    
      @Input() FinalPageComponent;
      summaryContent: SummaryContent;
    
      constructor(public data: InvestmentStrategyDigitalDataService, private router: Router, private sharedService: InvestmentSharedService) {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadPageContent();
      }
    
      loadPageContent(): void {
        this.summaryContent = new SummaryContent();
        this.summaryContent.summaryHeader = this.tridionContent.FINAL_PAGE_HEADER;
        this.summaryContent.summarySubHeader = this.tridionContent.FINAL_PAGE_SUBHEADER;
        this.summaryContent.summaryFundsSelectedHeader = this.tridionContent.FINAL_PAGE_FUNDS_SELECTED_HEADER;
        this.summaryContent.summaryReportHeader = this.tridionContent.FINAL_PAGE_REPORT_HEADER;
        this.summaryContent.summaryEmailLabel = this.tridionContent.EMAIL_REPORT_LABEL;
        this.summaryContent.summaryDownloadLink = this.tridionContent.FINAL_PAGE_DOWNLOAD_LINK;
        this.summaryContent.summaryInvestmentApproach = this.tridionContent.INVESTMENT_APPROACH_SELECTED;
        this.summaryContent.summaryTdf = this.tridionContent.TDF_APPROACH;
      }
    }
```

**Spec file:**

```
 import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    
    import { SummaryContentComponent } from './summary-content.component';
    import { SummaryContent } from './model/summary-content';
    
    describe('SummaryContentComponent', () => {
      let component: SummaryContentComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<SummaryContentComponent>;
      const contextPageContent = new SummaryContent();
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ SummaryContentComponent ],
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        })
          .compileComponents();
      });
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SummaryContentComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        contextPageContent.summaryHeader = 'Test';
        component.summaryContent = contextPageContent;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        expect(component.summaryContent.summaryHeader).toEqual('Test');
      });
    });
```

**Error:**

```
 FAIL   investment-shared-ui-components  libs/investment/shared/ui-components/src/lib/summary-content/summary-content.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at onResult (../../../../node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:175:18)
      at ../../../../node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:316:17
      at ../../../../node_modules/emittery/index.js:260:13
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Emittery.emit (../../../../node_modules/emittery/index.js:258:23)
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

You're using `describe` to set the description for the test, but you're not actually opening any tests.

`describe('SummaryContentComponent', () => {` should be followed by something like:

`test('This is the name of your test', async () => { /** test in here **/ }`

Comment: there is a test with name should create with in describe